# Plasma shell not logging in

Tags: login, plasma, kde5

Plasma shell is not logging in anymore. I've created a new user and it seems to work fine with this user.
I've tried to delete the cache folder the config and also the file in `/var/tmp/kdecache-user` with no luck.

Is there some other files or something else that I need to do to fix this?

Comment: did you have another desktop before you installed kde?

Answer (score 0):

Create new user and try to move users files partially and log. Be aware that kde/plasma 5 uses .kde, .config, .local. And some tools like network manager can have it's own files in /etc/ .

It will take a lot of time, but if there is no info in logs, you can determine which files create problems with logging, and in the end - manage to have working desktop.